# Groovy: pop the last element from a string list

Tags: list, testing, groovy, spock, geb

In my spock test class, I have the following two lists:

```
@Shared def orig_list = ['東京（成田・羽田）', '日本','アジア' ]
@Shared def dest_list = ['ソウル', '韓国','アジア' ]


def "Select origin"()
{
    when:
    something()

    then:
    do_something()


    where:
        area << orig_list.pop()
        country << orig_list.pop()
        port << orig_list.pop()
        dest_area << dest_list.pop()
        dest_country << dest_list.pop()
        dest_port << dest_list.pop()
}
```

But getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't select option with text or value: ア....
```

But If I do not use where block and do like:

```
def "Select origin"()
{
    def area = orig_list.pop()
    def country = orig_list.pop()
    def port = orig_list.pop()

    def dest_area = dest_list.pop()
    def dest_country = dest_list.pop()
    def dest_port = dest_list.pop()

    when:
    something()

    then:
    do_something()
}
```

Than it works fine.

How can I get the values in where block from list? What was the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables defined in the where block expects lists, but the pop() method returns an element in your list, which in your case seems to be a string.

Either wrap the `list.pop()` in brackets, like this `[list.pop()]` or, perhaps better, rewrite your where block to use the column syntax, i.e. something like this:

```
    where:
    area | country | port | dest_area | dest_country | dest_port
    'a1' | 'c1'    | 'p1' | 'da1'     | 'dc1'        | 'dp1'
    'a2' | 'c2'    | 'p2' | 'da2'     | 'dc2'        | 'dp2'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful answer. I did not notice that where block is expecting a list there.